# import .h at another .h

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I know that the convention is to do any kind of header in your .m. However, what if I need to import something so that I can have access to the protocol? Say I have a class Test.h/m and I have a protocol called TestProtocol that another class say, MyTest.h wants to implement. What I usually do in this case is to import Test.h in MyTest.h class file. I find this a bit distracting, is there a way to avoid this? What are some cases when this is fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the protocol in it's own TestProtocol.h and import that in MyTest.h.

This is the way I do it for delegate protocols etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the TestProtocol protocol in a separate TestProtocol.h file that you import wherever you want, or you can use a forward protocol declaration

```
@protocol TestProtocol;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no rule that says a .h file has to have a corresponding .m file.
So you could declare your protocol in TestProtocol.h and import that wherever it's needed.

Comment: I know.. I just want to keep it tidy

Comment: Well, that depends on your design.  If the protocol is useful in a general way, it probably belongs in it's own file.  If it's only useful with a class - for example, when that class selects something and calls back to inform it's caller - then I'd put it in the header of the class.